# How to re-render a partial only and not the full page with express-handlebars view engine?

Tags: jquery, ajax, express, handlebars.js

Consider the case where there are two dropdowns on a page. A dropdown menu for countries, and a dropdown menu for regions that should update based on the country selected from the first menu. We have some backend logic that dictates how each dropdown should be populated. T

partials/region-dropdown.handlebars:

```
<select class="region" name="region" id="region">
  {{#each regionList}}
    <option value="{{@index}}">{{this}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

When I first load the view and layout that holds this partial, the region dropdown is populated correctly with the regionList array that is passed when rendering the page with express for the first time.

I have a jquery ajax call that occurs whenever the country dropdown on that page changes, it is supposed to update the options within the dropdown within region-dropdown.handlebars only. I try to re-render this partial with the following code:

```
/** Load Partial */
app.get('/region-dropdown', function(req, res) {
  res.render('partials/region-dropdown',
      {
        layout : false,
        data : {
          regionList : ["Austria", "Switzerland"]
        }
      }
  );
});
```

However, what is rendered is just the dropdown without any options. It does not look like the regionList data is successfully passed to the partial. How can I ensure that the partial will get populated with the regionList data? Right now I am able to successfully pass back the partials/region-dropdown html to the ajax query. The problem is that there are no options being generated from the regionList data provided.

Comment: Have you figured out how to do this yet?

Comment: Nope -- just did a hack to get around it -- would still love to see a proper answer

Comment: what is the result of success callback of jquery ajax call?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this. If not, what is the hack that worked ??